# Expand DIV element from Right to Left with a grid layout and floats

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I am not sure that this is entirely possible.  I am using `display:grid` to build the layout of my page and I know that I can't use `float` with grid items, however I am trying to manipulate content inside of a grid item with floats and that doesn't appear to be working either.

My layout basically boils down to this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .page-container{
            display:grid;
            grid-template-columns: 4fr .25fr;
            grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
            height:100vh;
        }
        .menu{
            grid-column: 2 / span 1;
            grid-row: 2 / span 2;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="menu">
            <div style="background-color:#000;width:100%;height:50px;margin-bottom:25px;"></div>
            <div style="background-color:#000;width:100%;height:50px;margin-bottom:25px;"></div>
            <div style="background-color:#000;width:100%;height:50px;margin-bottom:25px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/dcparsons/pen/QBZXGB)

What I want to have happen is that when a user hovers over any of the items in the menu div I want the width to transition to 200px (or some other width that is not relative to the container).  I specifically want the right edge of the div to be anchored so that the width grows from right to left, rather than left to right. This is easy enough to do by using `right: 0` however this causes the grid column to expand as well thus shrinking the first column. Instead I would like the divs to expand outside of the menu container's width thus overlapping column 1 and column 2 in the overall grid.

Is there a way to achieve this using CSS and/or JavaScript?  I would prefer a CSS solution but either would work.

Comment: Can you illustrate/mockup how you want it to look? Your description isn't sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can animate `margin-left` with a negative value:

```css
.page-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4fr .25fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 100vh;
}

.menu {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}

.menu>div {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  transition:all 1s;
  margin-left:0;
}
.menu>div:hover {
   margin-left:-200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I don't think we need to add the width ... if we keep it auto it expand alone with the margin

Comment: You're correct. However, in a real world scenario, the content of that thing is going to be a mess during transition, methinks.